# C# how to change sort order in fast report

Tags: c#, report, reporting, fastreport

```
report1.Load("C:\\test.frx");
(report1.FindObject("Data1") as DataBand).Sort.Add(new Sort("[Product.Cost]"));
```

is working.

How to change Sort order `Ascending` OR `Descending` in C#???

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size:

```
new Sort(String column, Boolean descending)
new Sort("[Product.Cost]", true) // For descending
new Sort("[Product.Cost]", false) // For ascending
```